# Where to report PyQT5 bug?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, bug-reporting

**Where can I report bugs related to PyQT5 / QT?**
For example if object is not emitting signal correctly (on some platforms) as stated in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions for reporting `Qt` bugs can be found [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Reporting_Bugs). As for `PyQt` you can using the [`PyQt` mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).