# How to make label hide fully when hide() is called?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do I get the label and box to hide fully not just half way?

Hidden widgets

[image]

non-hidden widgets

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Code'
        self.left = 1400
        self.top = 500
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 168
        self.initUI()
        self.count = 0

    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('button', self)
        self.button.move(7,42)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.test)

        self.box = QLineEdit(self)
        self.box.setGeometry(5,19,20,20)
        self.box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.box.hide()

        self.l = QLabel(self)
        self.l.setText('Letters:')
        self.l.move(26,20)
        self.l.hide()

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def test(self):
        if self.count % 2 == 0:
            self.box.show()
            self.l.show()
        elif self.count % 2 == 1:
            self.l.hide()
            self.box.hide()
        self.count += 1
        print('Box: ', self.box.isVisible())
        print('Label: ', self.l.isVisible())
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am trying to get my label and show on first click then hide on second click but on the first click is shows but on the second click it hides half of if.

Comment: I do not observe the problem that you point out, you could show an image of the problem

Comment: What version of pyqt5 are you using? I recommend using the latest version 5.12.1. IMHO is a bug that only affects MacOS, in Linux it works correctly.

Comment: I am using PyQt5-5.12.1

Comment: I recommend you report the bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug

Comment: I've never seen the behaviour you describe and I cannot reproduce it on Linux. BTW: instead of setting the geometry manually and moving the widgets at specific positions you should reall use `QVBoxLayout` for example... will save you a lot of time & headaches