# PyQt5 Label setText Strange Behaviour

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new on Python and PyQt5. start learning now, but I found out there is a strange behaviour on running the code. below is my development environment

- OS : MacOS
- Python Version : Python 3.8
- Qt version : PyQt5
- IDE : VS Code for mac

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Using Labels")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 350, 350)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.text = QLabel("My Text", self)
        enterbutton = QPushButton("Enter", self)
        exitbutton = QPushButton("Exit", self)
        self.text.move(160, 50)
        enterbutton.move(100, 80)
        exitbutton.move(200, 80)
        enterbutton.clicked.connect(self.enterFunc)
        exitbutton.clicked.connect(self.exitFunc)
        self.show()

    def enterFunc(self):
        self.text.setText("You Click Enter")
        self.text.resize(150, 20)

    def exitFunc(self):
        self.text.setText("You Click Exit")
        self.text.resize(150, 20)


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

whatever using VS Code debugger function or direct run the script in terminal. when I click the button, the text will not update, until I change the focus out of main windows and focus it back. is there any hints why this happen? Thanks for help

Comment: The same happens when you run it in the terminal? I think it's a bug, I don't know if PyQt or Qt, what version of PyQt5 do you use?

Comment: I think is 5.13.2

Comment: here is the short movie link : https://imgur.com/vWIv1EF

Comment: mmm, it is probably a Qt bug that can be caused by some MacOs driver since your logic is correct. Report it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug