# PyQt5 have no sctp and dtls api?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I try to read some infomation about network, but i found there is no `sctp` and `dtls` in PyQt5 api,if my app may use it, how can i do?

Comment: sctp and dlts are supported by Qt so I think it is a PyQt5 bug so I recommend reporting it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug

Comment: @eyllanesc i had send a email to it.